# How to add my nodejs server to startup program of window?

Tags: node.js, window, startup, startupscript

I want the server made with Node.js to start automatically when Windows is operating.

I know that Windows runs the exe files in the StartUp folder when it is run.

But I've never made an exe file. (I am not sure how to do it).

I think there are probably many different ways to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

I'm not sure which way would be more efficient.

Please advise.

*I prefer to create automatic commands with the .sh.
It would be great if you could do it this way.*

Comment: I'd suggest do use something like [node-windows](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-windows) to create a windows-service from your node applcation. This way, it can even be started, when no user is looged on. But be aware that the current version (1.0.0-beta.7) has some issue with it's dependencies. Until those are fixed use 1.0.0-beta.6 instead

Comment: @derpirscher
Thanks my app is tiny little proxy server I think it would fit with that beta module